# Login with Yii2 and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, authentication, yii2-advanced-app

i tried to login with mongodb in yii2 advanced framework but i am getting this error:

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException 
>  Setting unknown
>   property: yii\mongodb\Connection::username

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fill the connection string in the `dsn` property.

```
[
     'components' => [
         'mongodb' => [
             'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
             'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
         ],
     ],
]
```

More info and examples in the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-connection.html)